# WSO2 PHP Framework consuming wsdl declared methods

Tags: php, wsdl, wso2

Good day. I want to consume a webservice declared in a wsdl in internet using PHP and the WSO2 framework (for streaming data reasons I need to use this). By reading documentation and examples I ended up with the following

```
    $wsclient = new WSClient(array("wsdl" => $director->getWsReport()));
    $proxy = $wsclient->getProxy();

    $ret_val = $proxy->getMessage($params);
```

where:

1.- $director->getWsReport() is the URL of the wsdl
2.- $params is an array (key->value) of parameters as defined in the xsd
3.- getMessage is the name of the method as defined in the wsdl

While debugging the segment above the $wsclient and $proxy are set but when I execute the "getMessage" method, I end up receiving nothing (no exceptions, no results) as if it was a timeout issue.

The service and methods are up since it was already tested.

Another issue (which I'm not sure if relevant) is that in netbeans the autocomplete options do not work for these framework elements. At first I thought it could have been installed incorrectly but by checking the phpinfo.php I can see all dependencies registered (exactly as the WSO2 installation tutorial indicated).

I'm sorry I cannot be more specific, but It's been hard finding documentation that could help directly with my problem. Hopefully I can find that missing expertise with you guys.

I thank you very much for your time and expect as well to receive useful data.